# What is the baseline for story point estimation in the Vikings team?

Tags: estimation

What is the baseline of story points in the Vikings team when establishing the effort on a story

Answer (score 0):

1 - greater 3 hours

3 - greater than 3 hours and less than 5 hours

5 - greater than 5 hours but less than 8 hours

8 - greater than 8 hours but less than 12 hours

10 - greater than 12 hours